# Git - Committing only my changes to a remote branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, spree

I'm using a forked repository of [spree-commerce](https://github.com/spree/spree) for my project.
So far, I was working and merging my changes to origin/2-3-stable and everything was peachy.
Problem is, SpreeCommerce release a new version (2-4) and created a new branch for it (2-4-stable):
merging my work into the newly created 2-4-stable branch means not only merging my own changes but also all the changes and conflicts between the two versions.

Iv'e tried creating a new branch based on 2-3 and cherry-pick my specific commits, but when I try merging it with 2-4 I get lot's of conflicts not related to these commits at all.

Is there anyway I can merge only my commits into the new branch without needing to resolve unrelated conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebase the upstream 2.4 branch onto your branch, i.e.:

```
git rebase origin/2-4-stable
```

Or, if your changes are in a few commits, you could checkout a new branch off 2.4 (not 2.3 as you did) and cherry pick your commits into that:

```
git checkout -b my-branch-on-top-of-2-4 origin/2-4-stable
git cherry-pick COMMIT
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to limit conflicts by doing a `git rebase --interactive origin/2-4-stable`, then remove all lines where you are not the author.